# Is it possible to import all files from a uploads DIR into WP media, retaining paths to the files

Tags: uploads, media

So i have a uploads DIR from a WP install.  I want to migrate that to my new site, retaining all the old paths  - so if something is in 2011/08  that path is kept and the file registered in the media section of WP admin

Comment: Do you need to migrate ONLY the attachments?

Answer (score 2):

If the images are attached to posts, when you export/import your WP data, there's a happy checkbox for pulling in the images.

If you just copied over the DB and all, just FTP the images over and they're fine.